# Ethernet problem on Ubuntu 20.04 in dual-boot with Windows

Tags: boot, networking, dual-boot, ethernet

I'll try and make this short,
Not that long ago I had Kali Linux but I didn't use it cause I couldn't get Ethernet on it so I uninstalled it and downloaded Ubuntu 20.04 today, I booted into it, installed some apps like discord etc. Then I restarted it to finish some update, once it was booted back into Ubuntu I had no internet.

But Whenever i'm using Windows to play a game or something and restart my computer to go into Ubuntu I get internet to work so it seems like Ethernet only works after I use windows and then restart my PC to get into Ubuntu.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please dit in information about the hardware: `lshw -class network` (run in terminal)

Comment: Here it is with the ethernet working, https://imgur.com/LzpYj3h

Comment: Before other troubleshooting make sure Fast Startup in Windows is disabled.

Comment: It is disabled, i made sure of that before posting this